# Movie with broadcast killer?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember old movie where man kill people with strange machine through tv broadcast.

Remembering that machine was actually a big, almost half room stand just in front of tv and at other end i think that man sitting to handle with it.

Remembering that at end of movie main good guy, some policeman/detective saw like laser dot (i think) on the woman/girl on some set, jump in push her aside and shot with the gun into camera... bullet travel through camera, from tv, to that machine and at the of machine kills the evil guy who operate with it.

I think 90% that is italian or maybe even french movie, from some 80s or 90s.

Seems like Kamikaze (1986)... but some scenes i found on YT not match with my memory !
And it haunt me that main good guy is Michele Placido from La Piovra - but cant find on imdb movie description that match with him  And i'm 90% sure its him as main good guy.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you've said you don't think it's *[Kamikaze](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091322/?ref_=kw_li_tt)* (1986), but there's a scene in that film very similar to the one you described.

The police don't yet know who the killer is, but with the help of several scientists they've essentially figured out how the murders are being committed, built a psychological profile of the killer, and figured out how to locate him if he uses his weapon again. They put out a broadcast specifically addressing the killer, in order to manipulate him into using his weapon so they can locate him and zap him with similar technology to the stuff he's using.

They have a device at the TV studio which lets them know when the killer is about to fire his weapon, and when the inspector leading the case sees it going off, he runs over to the woman speaking to the killer on camera and pushes her out of the way. Then, after angrily berating the killer and goading him to shoot, he fires his version of the weapon at the camera, sending a signal to the killer's home which causes his machine to short circuit and blow up, knocking the killer unconscious.

This scene occurs about an hour into the movie, not at the end, but you might've thought that was the end (and that the killer was dead) if you stopped watching there for whatever reason.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get to big mess with this movie.  I find a scene from Kamikaze with bottle cap and ceiling, and my bro think that he recognize the movie, and its what i search for but again he is not so sure !        And today when i go to shop i hit on the girl from neighborhood and asked her does she maybe know old movie where man kills people through tv broadcast with some weird machine.   She say... yea i remember - it was actor from La Piovra tv show.. at end he shot with gun into camera and with that he kills evil guy.   Now i don't know what to think she remember same as me.

Comment: If Michele Placido did a movie like this, it should be possible to confirm that by looking at [his filmography](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0686375/). I clicked on everything he did in the '80s and '90s, and didn't find a film resembling the one you described. I didn't find any film he was in that had any obvious science fiction elements at all. I also cannot find any other film (with any actor) which is as similar to your description as _Kamikaze_. I recommend that you watch _Kamikaze_ in full, not just isolated scenes on YouTube.

Comment: Don't know where to find full movie !

Comment: I gonna accept your answer because it seems that there is no any similar movie and it only have to be Kamikaze. Although i just fine remember almost all scenes different same as my neighbor.   Man saw laser dot on woman chest jump in the set push her aside and with normal gun fire into camera and killing bad guy.   That is how i remember it and my neighbor also.

Comment: Thanks. You can always remove the acceptance from this answer if a better answer is posted, or if you otherwise learn of a film that more closely matches your memory. If you do figure out that it was a different film, you can post the answer here yourself and accept that answer instead of mine. Also, I'll keep an eye out for any closer matches myself, and if I find one, I will post it.