# Movie about shooting TV presenters through the TV

Tags: story-identification, movie

Many years ago I saw a French language film where a grumpy retired inventor built himself a sort of TV feedback blaster which he could use to shoot on-screen TV presenters from his home. It looked like a periscope that he pulled down from the ceiling above his armchair.

After the first two victims the TV station insisted on a seven second delay on all live TV broadcasts to defeat it, so the third lady he tried to shoot survived. But she was aware of the attack and finished her piece to camera in tears.

I don't remember any more about the plot: what his grudge was, or if he got caught. I think he lived alone in an apartment in Paris, but did get visitors at some point and had to hide or explain away the periscope. It felt like it was from the early 80s (colour, tone, CRTs, magnetic tape for the seven second delay machine?) and I probably saw it 2000-2005 on Channel 4 in the UK. Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Kamikaze](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091322/)* (1986)

> A crazy old and bored scientist invents a system which allows him to reach through the airwaves and transform live TV cameras into weapons to kill whoever is being filmed.

Found with a search for `french film inventor kill "tv presenters"`

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like a forerunner of the [Death Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note) series

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250660/movie-with-broadcast-killer/250666#250666

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Yes I think that's it. I don't recognise the pictures on IMDB but the plan to trap the inventor in the answer on the other Q is the bit I remember about the delay loop.

Comment: I had tried searching myself honestly but always got generic articles about TV studios :-/ nothing like the actual film. And the other Q here never came up either.

Comment: @Rup I only found the other question after searching by name. :) Part of why we do the Duplicate system is that it will hopefully help provide relevant questions/answers in the future. You did everything right here.